# API Calling in Swift with Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift

Below is code which I have used for API calls, here any other way to decrease this code for all view controller. Can I create a model class of alamofire API calls?

[image: Login Screen]

```
 func ForgotPasswordServiceCall()  {
    
    
    let params = [
        "email":EmailTextField.text!,
        ]
    
    let strUrl = "forgotPassword?"
    
    PKHUD.sharedHUD.contentView = PKHUDProgressView()
    PKHUD.sharedHUD.show()
    
    Alamofire.request(strUrl, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody)
        .responseJSON{ response in
            
            PKHUD.sharedHUD.hide()
            if((response.result.value) != nil)
            {
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
                
                if let resData = swiftyJsonVar.dictionaryObject
                {
                    
                    if(resData["status"] as! String == "success")
                    {
                      //self.arrData = resData["result"] as! [[String:String]]
                      //self.arrData = resData["result"] as! [NSDictionary]
                     //cel.text=self.arrData[indexPath.row].object(forKey:""] 
                     //as! NSString)as String 
                    }else{
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "decrease the code"?

Comment: I don't t think you can make it smaller, but if you will be calling that from different view controllers you could make a struct singleton of the call and create a completion handler for the function and then call it from other view controllers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can for sure cut down your code for all view controllers  -

1. Make a base class that will handle all rest api requests (GET,POST,PUT etc).
2. Make model classes for JSON objects .

Let me give you an example for this -

Base class -

```
class WebServiceHandler : NSObject {


override init() {
    // perform some initialization here

}


func processSingleRecord() -> Bool {
    return false
}

func getWebServiceUrl() -> String{
    return ""
}
func DisplayNetworkAvailabilityMessage()-> String{
    return "network failed"
}

func fetchDataFromWebServicePost<T: Mappable>(_ parameters: Dictionary<String , AnyObject>, closure:@escaping (_ response: T) -> Void) {

    let url = getWebServiceUrl()
     Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            //                print(response.data)     // server data
            print("Result",response.result)   // result of response serialization
            print("parameters = \(parameters)")
            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            switch response.result {
            case .success(_):
                if response.response?.statusCode == 200 || response.response?.statusCode == 201 {
                    var user = Mapper<T>().map(JSONObject: response.result.value)
                    if self.processSingleRecord() == true {
                        user = Mapper<T>().map(JSONObject: (response.result.value as! NSArray).object(at: 0))
                    }
                    closure(user! )
                }
                else if response.response?.statusCode == 0{

                }
                else  {
                    if let _ = response.result.value as? Error {
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                debugPrint("getEvents error: \(error)")
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            }
        }.responseString { response in
            //                print("Success: \(response.result.isSuccess)")
            //                print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
    }
} }
```

Your model class for a single api -

```
    class DeviceTokenDataHandler : WebServiceHandler
  {

    override func getWebServiceUrl() -> String{
        return ApiLinks.sharedInstance.deviceTokenLink()
    }

    override func DisplayNetworkAvailabilityMessage()-> String{
        return "Check your internet connection"
    }    

}
```

ApiLinks class where you define all the api links -

```
import Foundation
class ApiLinks : NSObject {

    var prod = Bool()
    var dev = Bool()
    var httpPart = "http://"

    var localHost = "put your base url here"
    var prodHost = "put your base url here"


    var apiExtension = ""//".php" for php apisf
    var separater = "/"
    var host = String()

    static let sharedInstance = ApiLinks()

    //handle the dev or prod modes    
    func setTheProdStatus(_ prodVaule : Bool) {
        prod = prodVaule
        if(prod) {
            host = prodHost
        } else {
            host = localHost
        }
    }

    let deviceToken = "updatedevicetoken" // your api name here
    func deviceTokenLink() -> String {
        return "\(httpPart)\(host)\(separater)\(deviceToken)\(apiExtension)"

}
```

Response model class -

```
    import ObjectMapper
import AlamofireObjectMapper
class DeviceTokenResponse: Mappable {
    var user_id: Int?
    var message: String?
    var status: String?
    required init?(map: Map){

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        user_id <- map["user_id"]
        message <- map["message"]
        status <- map["status"]
    }
}
```

Now this is how you make a call to api from viewcontroller -

```
func updateDeviceToken() {        
        let anotherWebServiceHandler = DeviceTokenDataHandler.init()
        anotherWebServiceHandler.fetchDataFromWebServicePost(["app_type":"user" as AnyObject], closure: { (response:SignUpResponse) -> Void in
            print(response.message);
        })
    }
```

Comment: Wow This is work like charm, yes i am looking for this model class.

Answer (score -2):

```
func APIcallingFunction() {
        APIMassnger.sharedInstance.getAPIMassngerDate(string: "https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users", completion: { (respondDate, isSuccess) in
            do{
                
                let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: respondDate) as? [[String:Any]]
                
                if let temp = parsedData {
                    
                    self.arrAllGateData.append(contentsOf: AllInfoGetDate().setDictionary(arrDictionary: temp))
                }
            }catch let err{
                print("errors : ",err.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
    }
```

1. APIMassnger class

> class APIMassnger {
>
> ```
> static let sharedInstance = APIMassnger()
>
> func getAPIMassngerDate(string: String, completion: ((_ success: Data, _ TNF: Bool) -> Void)?) {
>     
>     AF.request(string).response { response in
>         switch(response.result) {
>         case.success(let data):
>             completion?(data ?? Data(), true)
>             break
>         case.failure(let error):
>             completion?(Data(), false)
>             print(error.localizedDescription)
>             break
>         }
>     }
>     
>     func postAPIMassngerDate(string: String) {
>
>     }
> } }
> ```

2. Models

> ```
> class AllInfoGetDate {
>     
>     func setDictionary(arrDictionary: [[String: Any]]) -> [AllInfoGetDate] {
>         
>         var arrAllInfoGetDate = [AllInfoGetDate]()
>         
>         for dictionary in arrDictionary {
>             let obje = AllInfoGetDate()
>             obje.id = dictionary["id"] as? Int
>             obje.email = dictionary["email"] as? String
>             obje.gender = dictionary["gender"] as? String
>             obje.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
>             obje.status = dictionary["status"] as? String
>             
>             arrAllInfoGetDate.append(obje)
>         }
>         return arrAllInfoGetDate
>     }
>     
>     var id: Int?
>     var name: String?
>     var email: String?
>     var gender: String?
>     var status: String?
>     
> }
> ```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).